# Mac OS X crahes during format USB to MBR, Mac Journalized in virtualbox

Tags: macos, virtualbox, osx-yosemite

I am using `OS X Yosemite` in `Virtualbox` on Windows 8. The problem is when I try to format (1 Partition, Mac OS Extended (Journaled) and Master Boot Record) it crashes.
What should I do?